# Is it possible to install "normal" Systembuilder Intel Xeon CPUs, instead of original HP branded Intel Xeons?

Tags: hp, intel, xeon

Can I install normal Systembuilder Intel Xeon CPUs for HP Proliant Server? instead of OEM HP branded  Intel Xeon CPUs?

The Systembuilder Intel Xeon CPUs is on the compatibility List for the HP Server Modell.

Will I lose my HP Carepack Support if I use non HP Branded CPUs?

Thanks very much for the information.

Comment: Ask you support contact how and if installing non-HP parts would impact your support contract. We've had responses varying between: go ahead no problem, you may be asked to remove those parts before making support claims and no you really shouldn't because of [valid/commercial/stupid] reasons.

Comment: Better off contacting your local HPE office.

Comment: The Support contract usually relies on parts that has not been modified or changed. the System must usually stay in its delivered state.